# C # fill datatable using loops - how?

Tags: c#, while-loop

First of all, I'm just a beginner in C#, so.....don't laugh :-)

OK, I have DataTable named "***Changeable***" with  Columns (**Id**, **A**, **B**, **C**, **D**, **Fdiv**).

The values of **A**, **B**, **C**, **D** are integers (numbers), **Fdiv** is decimal number with 13 decimal places and **Id** is AutoNumber.

I have four(4) counters( loops) like code below, with all possible No. of combination is 21^4

```
for ( int A = 10; A <= 31; A++)
        {
            for ( int B = 10; B <= 31; B++)
            {
                for ( int C = 10; C <= 31; C++)
                {

                    for ( int D = 10; D <= 31; D++)
                    {                            

                        while (A == 31)
                        {
                          Fdiv = A/B * C/D
                     //Code to fill all 5 values in
                    // DataTable "Changeable", automatic

                        }
                      }
                 }
            }
          }
```

How to do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Aside from the database problem, you're looping while A=31 but never changing A within the loop. So the loop will either never run or loop infinitely.

Comment: If you're a C# beginner....don't bother learning about DataTable. Learn to create strongly typed model objects instead.

Answer (score 2):

Filling a data table with a loop.

```
    private void AddDataToDGV()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        //create some columns for the datatable
        DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("ItemName");
        DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("ItemValue");
        DataColumn dc3 = new DataColumn("Blah");
        DataColumn dc4 = new DataColumn("Bleh");
        //add the columns to the datatable
        dt.Columns.Add(dc);
        dt.Columns.Add(dc2);
        dt.Columns.Add(dc3);
        dt.Columns.Add(dc4);

        //create 5 rows of irrelevant information
        //this is the actual answer to your question
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();//create a new row based on the existing "row model"
            dr["ItemName"] = "Item" + i + "Name";
            dr["ItemValue"] = "Item" + i + "Value";
            dr["Blah"] = "Item" + i + "Blah";
            dr["Bleh"] = "Item" + i + "Bleh";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);//add the row to the DataTable
        }


    }
```